# Text alignment isn't working the way it's intended, is there any other way to do it?

Tags: html, css, text-align

I'm really new to using both HTML and CSS, so any advice is welcome. I've been running into some problems with two hyperlinks sharing the same class which are both supposed to pose as buttons.

Right now I'm trying to make the text inside both buttons align in the center of their respective backgrounds but `align-text: center` doesn't work and most other responses I have found have been too complicated for a starter like me to comprehend (trust me, if at least I knew where to place those eldritch scribings I'd at least test what the results end up being). Also, for some reason `flex-direction` doesn't seem to work so the solution I could find is use `display: inline-flex` instead of `diplay: flex`.

Up to this point I tried using:

HTML:

```
<a class="presentation__content__links" href="linktothewebsite.com"> Yada yada </a>
```

CSS:

```
.presentation__content__links: { 
    display: inline-flex; 
    text-align: center; 
}
```

I also tried this:

HTML

```
<div class="presentation__content__links">
    <a class="presentation__content__links__link" href="linktothewebsite.com"> Yada yada </a>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.presentation__content__links: { 
    text-align: center; 
}

.presentation__content__links__link { 
    display: inline-flex; 
    text-aling: center; 
 }
```

Because I read it could align the child with the parent and by that point I was already kind of desperate. If it's a necessity I can post the entirety of the code while censoring the hyperlinks, it's just short of 120 lines.

Comment: You don't need to post the entirety of the code, just enough to reproduce the problem. Welcome to Stack Overflow, but please take the time to learn how to use this platform. [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

```
 .presentation__content__links{ 
display: flex; 
**justify**-content: center;
```

}
/*you just need to justify content centre . Justify content centre makes the content align in the centre along the horizontal path.*/

Comment: Thank you very much! It worked, although I'll still need to figure out how to make it align vertically. But that I can figure out on my own, hope you have a great week and thanks again!

Answer (score -1):

You can try this

```
.presentation__content__links__link{ 
   display: inline-flex;
   justify-content: center
 }
```

Hope it will work for you

Comment: Thank you! Even though I still need to figure out the vertical alignment part, at least my current problem is fixed. Thanks again, hope you have a great week!

Comment: @macaconheiro sounds good. If it will work for you  the you can apply `align-items: center` to the same element. 
Hope it will work for you.